# Ordering a (Django) list from a template

Tags: python, django

I have created a form which returns information to a list in a table, using a mako template. I have it set up to order the list alphabetically from A-Z when the list name is clicked, within the template and views.

The problem is, I want to be able to order it from Z-a if it is clicked again. 
Here is my view:

```
    def people(request):

        sort = request.GET.get('sort','')
        if sort != '':
            var = sort
            ppl = People.objects.order_by(var)
    else:
        ppl = People.objects.all()
```

And my template.mako:

```
    <table class="table overview-table table-hover" id="people">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th><a href="${self.util.reverse('view_people')}?sort=first_name">First Name</th>
          <th><a href="${self.util.reverse('view_people')}?sort=surname">Last name</th>

        </tr>
      </thead>
```

Any ideas on how to get this to work

Answer (score 0):

I would say use [django-tables2](http://django-tables2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) to display any tables. It comes with built in functionality to sort by any column, in either direction when a user clicks on the column's header. It's very full featured, and will be a lot easier to use than trying to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: I was looking into Django Tables 2 but unfortunately the project manager doesnt want to use it for this project

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll have to create an additional variable for your sorting hyperlink's query string, called something like "sort_direction".  When your sort href is clicked, your view can then set that variable to "desc" and pass it into the template.  Then when your view receives it again and sees "desc" in the GET variable, you can reverse the order from Django's ORM:

`ppl = People.objects.order_by('-var')`

Answer (score 0):

How about [Tablesorter](http://tablesorter.com/docs/)?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/path/to/jquery-latest.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="/path/to/jquery.tablesorter.js"></script>

$(document).ready(function() 
{ 
    $("#myTable").tablesorter(); 
} );
```